# google Adsense in iphone application

Tags: ios4, iphone, adsense

I developed an iphone application , But i need to put **google Adsense** in my application,
I know how to put apple iAds because there is a control for it , BUT i do not found control for google adsense . 
Any idea or solution or advice

:)

Comment: I believe Google intends for mobile apps to use their AdMob SDK. Use Adsense for mobile websites.

Comment: @Saurabh you should post this as an answer. In my opinion AdMob is the only correct answer. Google thinks the same, they redirect everybody searching for "Adsense in mobile apps" to use AdMob

Comment: @Saurabh hi,i listen about AdMob , but i do not know if it support iphone application,On the other hand if it support iphone apps how can i use it?? any idea about it ?:)

Comment: Looks like you need to do some research of your own, or at least open AdMob's webpage and give it a slight reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google intends for mobile apps to use their AdMob SDK. Use Adsense for mobile websites.

If you still insist on using your Adsense account for iOS apps, there's a Google Labs project that you could experiment with. It can be found [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a webView and the link for webView will be a link to you ads page.

Comment: @raj2raaz thanks,, 
But you sure that if i take the link for the google Adsense and a a singed this like to the UIWebView ,do you expect the UIWebView will understand the structure for the Adsense or i must additional things?

Comment: there are a lot of people that believe that this is a violation of the adsense terms

Comment: @ fluchpunkt if this is a violation for adsense...what is the solutions??
i.e how can i display google adsense in my iphone app.??

Comment: when you google for `AdSense for Mobile Applications` the first link is a page from google that will tell you to use AdMob

Comment: @ fluchtpunkt i see that you know about AdMob, so is it support iphone apps?? and how can use it in iphone ??:)